# C++ friend class std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, friend

Is it possible to do the following portably:

```
struct structure {
    structure() {}
private:
    // only allow container copy construct
    structure(const structure&) {}
    // in general, does not work because allocator (not vector) calls copy construct
    friend class std::vector<structure>;
};
```

example message trying to compile above:

```
In member function void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, const _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = kernel_data<const double*>::block]:
...
/usr/include/c++/4.3/ext/new_allocator.h:108: error: within this context
```

Thanks

I do have workaround, but I am curious as how this could be possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `vector` (more precisely, the allocator passed into `vector`) can delegate the task of construction to a free function or another class, making the `friend`ship useless.

Even if you pass your own allocator, it may be rebound to a class internal to the implementation. Then the constructor for *your* class may be accessed from that class, not your allocator. So if that's your workaround, it's not guaranteed. (Although looking at GCC's implementation, it does scrupulously use the un-rebound allocator to construct such subobjects.)

In GCC's libstdc++, no STL container template constructs the contained objects in the scope of a standard class or function.

Comment: no, my workaround was to forgo copy constructor entirely.
Thanks

Comment: @aaa: How can you use a class within a container without a copy constructor? More likely you are using the implicit copy constructor.