# No matching constructor for initialisation of 'value type'

Tags: c++, constructor, value-type

I have got some code that gets the most frequent words and puts them into a vector. I then sort the vector into numerical order and all this works fine. I then try to resize the vector to 10 so I can get the top ten that I want to sort by word.

I think the problem lies with part of my struct but i am not to sure here is the code i am using.

```
struct wordFreq
{
    string word;
    int count;

    wordFreq(string str, int c): word(str),count(c) { }
}; 

words.resize(10);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the entire code? Please post more.

Comment: You should tell us what is this `words` variable and how it is declared. We can't link the `wordFreq` class and the variable like this.

Comment: This seems like the same thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687152/stl-vector-and-c-how-to-resize-without-a-default-constructor

Comment: Why are you resizing to get the top ten elements ? Use the sorting algorithms available i.e. partial_sort, nth_element.

Comment: What is the error you get? Can you post more code here?

Comment: @J.N. the words variable is a variable of the struct storing words and there occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When resizing the vector, the function `resize` needs to know the value for the new elements. Therefore, the call

```
words.resize(10);
```

includes a default argument of the form `wordFreq()`, which is invalid in your case, since the class `wordFreq` doesn't have a default constructor.

If no new elements are being created, use `erase` instead of `resize`.

```
words.erase(words.begin() + 10, words.end());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `words.erase(words.begin() + 10, words.end());`?

Comment: thanks that worked i had tried this before but it didn't work, but this one does thanks.

Comment: @bobthemac: Just make sure that your `vector` contains at least 10 elements though..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `vector::resize` vector tries to create `10` object using *default ctor* of `wordFreq` class. Since there is no default ctor available you get a compiler error. For the case you are mentioning there is no need to use the `resize` method, you can simply loop through `1..10` to use the top 10 elements as you have already sorted the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a default constructor, since vector uses it to make room for new elements.

```
wordFreq() : word(""), count(0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

`vector::resize` function requires items to have a constructor with no parameters (default constructor). See the section "Requirements for Container Elements" in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fe2x6kt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The sentence "some operations on containers might also require a public default constructor" relates to `vector::resize`.