# How to resize vector of struct?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, resize

I've tried to resize my vector of struct, but VS throws me an error

```
Error   C2512   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual 
studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0(856): 
error C2512: 'tabuRecord::tabuRecord': no appropriate default constructor 
available
```

Here is my struct:

```
struct tabuRecord {
  int x;
  int y;
  int k;
  tabuRecord(int x1, int y1, int k1) { x = x1; y = y1; k = k1; }
};
```

Here is my resizing function:

```
void insertToTabu(vector<tabuRecord> &v, int sizeOfTabuList) {
  v.resize(sizeOfTabuList);
}
```

Comment: For resizing a vector of structs, your struct must be default constructible.
You can add a default constructor which does nothing, then it should work.

Comment: Related question : [stl vector and c++: how to .resize without a default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687152/stl-vector-and-c-how-to-resize-without-a-default-constructor)

Comment: @ThomasLang and potentially invalidate a variant?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, but as long as the default contructability of OPs struct does not contradict the intended program logic, it should be fine.

Comment: @ThomasLang user-defined constructors are an indispensable tool in supporting class invariant. Granted, OP's type doesn't have one (and in fact would be better served by being an aggregate), but if we take a step back and generalize the example, we can understand that adding default constructor is often not applicable solution.

Comment: @SergeyA Ah, yes, I totally agree.

Comment: `tabuRecord(int x1, int y1, int k1) { x = x1; y = y1; k = k1; }` - Please don't do that (use the constructor body), use the initialisation list instead when you can (like here). It will be faster since then you don't have to first default construct member variables and subsequently assign to them - you'll just initialize them once.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `std::vector::resize(X)`, you are asking vector to (at least, potentially) create `X` objects. The only way vector can do this is by default-construction them - because you are not giving it anything else. And since your struct doesn't have a default constructor, `resize` can't be compiled.

And just in case, your struct doesn't have default constructor because you have declared a user constructor.